# Having an employee move teams because you feel they're better suited elsewhere, but they want to stay?

Tags: ethics, team, employees, team-role

I have an employee who really excels at designing and implementing web interfaces for things like APIs, however, the team the employee is currently on focuses primarily on lower level monitoring tools we build in-house, which, while the employee was a good fit years ago when the employee came on board, the employee seems to struggle with as technology grows in this area.  I've approached this employee about switching to the API team which seems better suited for the employee, however the employee wanted to stay on this current team.  While I feel I would not hire the employee now for this current position, I recognize the employee is a great engineer still, just better suited elsewhere.  Would it be wrong to give the employee a nudge towards the API team, so to speak?

Comment: Does the API team historically get smaller raises or aren't considered "real" computer scientists/software engineers? The employee may also be thinking about his or her resume and the job titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could understand concerns coming from this employee.  Like "What if this would require learning a new language?" and they are not a ployglot.  Or "I'm really familiar with this codebase, but I have no idea about that codebase". Or simply, that's not where their interests lie.

On the other hand, a bad fit is misusing resources.  Sounds like this is a decision left for you to make, but feel free to consult higher ups for input.  Additionally, you can try to find a middle ground where they still have what interests them, but they're being used effectively.

It is also valuable to explain why they'd be a good fit on the other team and that, like you said, you still find them to be a great engineer.  But also explain that they would be very valuable over on the other team.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to sell the move to employee. That its positive move for them. That will be their primary concern.